# Combine CSV files and concatenate some columns into single column via AIX awk, sed, ksh

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ksh, aix

I have multiple files like so:

```
File_1.csv:
"Job Id", "Batch Id","Id","Success","Created","Error","Col1","Col2","Col3"
 aaabbb111,xxxyyy999,"false","false","Horrible_Error: Really Bad Error occured: yeah", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3"
 cccddd222,pppqqq888,"","false","Horrible_Error: Anoter Bad Error occured: ouch", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3"

File_2.csv:
"Job Id", "Batch Id","Id","Success","Created","Error","Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4", "Col5"
 aaabbb111,xxxyyy999,"false","false","Horrible_Error: Really Bad Error occured: oops","Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5"
 cccddd222,pppqqq888,"","false","Horrible_Error: Anoter Bad Error occured: oh-no", "Val1","Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5"
```

First 6 columns in each file always have the same names. The names and number of remaining columns varies and I would like to capture them as single column surrounded by double-quotes, square or curly brackets or anything that would denote that this is the same data.

I need to be able to combine these files into a single file that will look like so. The header is optional and shown for illustration only:

```
"File_Name"|"Job Id"|"Batch Id"|"Id"|"Success"|"Created"|"Error"|"Tran_Header"|"Tran_Record" 
File_1.csv|aaabbb111|xxxyyy999|"false"|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Really Bad Error occured: yeah"|["Col1","Col2","Col3"]|["Val1","Val2","Val3"]
File_1.csv|cccddd222|pppqqq888|""|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Anoter Bad Error occured: ouch"|["Col1","Col2","Col3"]|["Val1","Val2","Val3"]
File_2.csv|aaabbb111|xxxyyy999|"false"|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Really Bad Error occured: oops"|["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4", "Col5"]|["Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5"]
File_2.csv|cccddd222|pppqqq888|""|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Anoter Bad Error occured: oh-no"|["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4", "Col5"]|["Val1","Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5"]
```

I tried the following to combine the files but this code sometimes chokes on replacing double-quotes, then my ETL tool in turn chokes on parsing the concatenated column set (and also I don't know how to capture the header into a separate column):

```
outdirectory=/some/directory
outfilename=some_file_name.csv
for i in *.csv
do
    filename=$(echo "${i}")

    tail +2 "${i}" | sed -e 's/,/#|#/1' -e 's/,/#|#/1' -e 's/,/#|#/1' -e 's/,/#|#/1' -e 's/,/#|#/1' -e 's/,/#|#/1' -e s/\"//g -e "s/^/#${filename}/" -e s/$/#/ | sed s/#/\"/g >> "${outdirectory}/${outfilename}" 

    mv $i $srcdir/
done
```

Any help or idea is greatly appreciated. I am total newb to UNIX shell scripting. Almost forgot, I am on AIX v6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution using `awk` (i use gnu-awk)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|"}
{
  if(FNR==1){
    if(NR==1){
      print "\"File_Name\"",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,"\"Tran_Header\"","\"Tran_Record\"";
    }
    $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6="";
    gsub("[|]+",",",$0);
    gsub("^,","",$0);
    titleCol = $0;
  }else{
    temp = FILENAME OFS $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS "["titleCol"]";
    $1=$2=$3=$4=$5="";
    gsub("[|]+",",",$0);
    gsub("^,","",$0);
    print temp OFS "["$0"]";
  }
}' *.csv
```

you get:

```
"File_Name"|"Job Id"|"Batch Id"|"Id"|"Success"|"Created"|"Error"|"Tran_Header"|"Tran_Record"
File_1.csv|aaabbb111|xxxyyy999|"false"|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Really Bad Error occured: yeah"|["Col1","Col2","Col3"]|["Val1","Val2","Val3"]
File_1.csv|cccddd222|pppqqq888|""|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Anoter Bad Error occured: ouch"|["Col1","Col2","Col3"]|["Val1","Val2","Val3"]
File_2.csv|aaabbb111|xxxyyy999|"false"|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Really Bad Error occured: oops"|["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5"]|["Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5"]
File_2.csv|cccddd222|pppqqq888|""|"false"|"Horrible_Error: Anoter Bad Error occured: oh-no"|["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5"]|["Val1","Val1","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5"]
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the main problem - as the columns after 6th are not combined into one. Also I would prefer not to hard-code the header and print it out as it appears.